# Undo deleting a commit while rebasing interactively

Tags: git

I interactively rebased my branch off of another branch, and in middle of way I deleted one of my commits.

Now I want it back. Is there a way to undo this delete? Is there a way to see all the commits, regardless of being deleted?

Comment: Take a look at either the old position of the branch or the original commit that you did (if you did) by checking `git reflog`.

Comment: I found the hash for the commit I'm looking for. Should I just reset it hard back to that commit?

Comment: You could cherry-pick it

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are on the right track, but one is confused and the other is too busy being smug to just help you understand how to deal with this situation.

`rebase` does not delete commits (not directly at least).  It never edits commits (that is impossible).  What it does is create new commits and move refs to point to the new commits instead of the old ones.  And often, especially when the moved refs are the only ones that were previously able to reach the old commit, that can make it *seem* like the old commits are gone.

But until either you take explicit steps to force those commits to really be deleted, or enough time passes to expire the relevant reflogs (by default something like a month), nothing is deleted.

So if you were rebasing `my_branch`, then *on the clone where you did the rebase* you can say

```
git reflog my_branch
```

and you'll get a list of different commits to which the ref has previously pointed.  Likely the `my_branch@{1}` will be what you want, and you can find the commits you want in the history reachable by that name.

Now, reflogs are temporary (though, as I say, by default they stay for a while), and they are local (i.e. they don't get pushed to the remote, if you use a remote).  So that specific approach may not work on other clones.

Of course, if you have a remote to which you've pushed the branch and haven't yet force-pushed the rebase, you can use that to find the old history - it would probably be reachable as `origin/my_branch`.

(Or you could similarly use any *other* clone that had pulled the branch, but not yet the rebase - though there may not be a convenient remote ref for that.)

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you are on branch1 and you were rebasing it on master.

Now, when you say you deleted a commit during interactive rebase, that means you decided to SKIP to include it in branch1 during rebase. Please note, it is not deleted from original branch master and still present there.

You need to just view history of master branch using (checkout on master branch)

`git log` and get commit-hash of the commit.

Then you can cherry pick the commit using (first checkout on branch1)

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

Comment: Rajni the revision Arian deleted was never on the other branch (he didn't specify) but on the topic branch he rebased (if I understood correctly) so if there's no reference set up on the old branch, there's only the reflog to look at the original branch/revisions to pick it up.

Comment: He mentioned that he deleted a commit during interactive rebase. As you said, he did not specify that the commit was never on any other branch. My answer is based on the assumption that he deleted it during interactive rebase (As the question title also says). But if your assumption is correct and commit reference is no where else, you are right, git reflog is the last option.